# Мануал или туториал по SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, база-данных

Я вот прорыл весь интернет, но не смог все же найти подробный туториал для использования SQLite и C#. Я хочу как бы с нуля выучить создание программ с Базами Данных. Помоги пожалуйста. Дайте советы с чего начать, что читать, куда смотреть. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы точно хотите выучить создание программ с базами данных? Я, конечно, против sqlite ничего не имею, но у sqlite обычно довольно специфическое применение. А по вопросу даже на первой странице гугла по запросу "C# sqlite" есть вполне адекватные результаты

Comment: @ramisha я не могу качать SQLite =( что делать? скачал из офф сайта, а там всего 1 экзешник, который при запуске открывается в консоли подобно MySQL. А в одном месте читаю, там говорится что должны быть библиотеки

Answer (score 2):

Библиотеки вот: [csharp-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) и [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 0):

По моему лучшей статьёй для самого начала работы с *sqlite*  [sqlite3-tutorial-and-guide](http://tech.marksblogg.com/sqlite3-tutorial-and-guide.html) там он правда в связке с питоном. В ней отлично раскрывается способность этой микропрограмки решать задачи аналитики и экспорти импорт данных из ней. Вот [перевод этой статьи](http://www.lshnk.me/minimalisticheskoe-rukovodstvo-po-sqlite.htm).

Ещё мне показалась [интересной эта статья](http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/) но в ней только основа работы из С#

Comment: Ну вы, блин, некрофил. И я на дату посмотрел лишь после того, как дал свой ответ.

Comment: Сорянчик. Наткнулся на вопрос когда самому пришлось с sqlite работать.

Answer (score 0):

Что именно качать с [официального](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) сайта SQLite, зависит от того, под какую платформу вы пишете. Идёте на вкладку [Download](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) и там выбираете нужный вам пункт:

- Universal Windows Platform
- Precompiled Binaries for Windows Phone 8
- Precompiled Binaries for Windows Runtime
- Precompiled Binaries for .NET

Вероятнее всего, вам нужен последний.

Самая точная и новая [документация](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html) там же (но на английском).

Если вы совсем новичок в базах данных, то берите любую книгу по основам языка SQL для начала.